# Remote software solution that acts as a client

Tags: remote-access

I have a remote computer that will not allow incoming traffic due to ISP blocking of ports (basically double NAT situation that I am unable to get around). I am wondering if I have a computer acting as a client, is there any solution out there that will allow remote access to the computer. I do have other servers on the net that have static IP's that the computer could initiate a connection with.

I am thinking of using Debian Linux, However computer is not built yet so OS is not overly important at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), which is free for personal use. It has gone through every firewall I've seen so far that doesn't EXCLUSIVELY block it, and lets you create a VPN tunnel, transfer files, etc between two computers

Answer (score 1):

Would ssh tunneling be an option? http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/04/how-to-do-ssh-tunneling-port-forwarding.html